# Javascript: Scope of variables - Clarification request

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I came across this piece of code from a friend and I'm wondering why is this working this way.

Assume two files: scope2.js and scope3.js

**scope2.js**

```
console.log(foo);
var foo=6;
woo=5;
(function()
{
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(woo);
    var foo=5;

console.log(foo);
console.log(woo);
})();
```

The output when executed in NodeJS env, >>> "node scope2.js"

> undefined undefined 5 5 5

**Now, Scope3.js**

```
console.log(foo);
var foo=6;
woo=5;
(function()
{
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(woo);
    var foo=5;
    var woo=6;
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(woo);
})();
```

Output of the above code in nodejs env is :

> undefined undefined undefined 5 6

Why this behavior ?

I understand most of the basics of variable scoping in JS, but this is confusing me, I dont want to understand something with some bad assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you miss is that variable declarations are "[hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)" to the start of their scope (which is either the function in which they're declared or the global scope).

So your second code is equivalent to

```
var foo;
console.log(foo); // undefined value
foo=6;
woo=5;
(function()
{
    var foo, woo; // shadow the external variables
    console.log(foo); // undefined value
    console.log(woo); // undefined value
    foo=5;
    woo=6;
    console.log(foo); // 5
    console.log(woo); // 6
})();
```

Those hoisted variable declaration shadow the external variable **from the start of the function** even if they get a value only after the two first `console.log`.

In the first code, the difference is that `woo` isn't declared in the inner scope, so you're logging the external value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. now i understood. but i also have another clarification:(from the link you gave from MDN)

var x = 0;
function f(){
  var x = y = 1; // x is declared locally. y is not!
}
f();

console.log(x, y); // 0, 1 ==> why 'y' leaked in here ?

Comment: @Futur `var` doesn't affect variables used after a `=`, so `var x = y = 1;` is actually `y = 1; var x = y;` and `y` is set without a declaration, which can result in it [becoming a global](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/). To declare and set both `x` and `y`, they should be comma-separated -- `var x, y; x = y = 1;` or `var x = 1, y = x;`